# How to request data from zkteco device

Tags: php, sdk, zkteco

I'm having trouble retrieving data from the fingerprint device such as user and attendance data, I want to save it into a MySQL database to be used in the application that I created.

when I open the IP of the fingerprint device with port 4370 in the browser I get an 'empty response'

I also got the ZKLIB PHP library and have adjusted the IP which is in the code

```
require 'zklibrary.php';

$zk = new ZKLibrary('192.168.50.236', 4370);
$zk->connect();
$zk->disableDevice();

$users = $zk->getUser();
```

but still it doesn't work

I've tried looking for an example project on the internet but couldn't find it,

is there any way to retrieve data from ZKTECO fingerprint wl20 device?, any help would be much appreciated

Comment: I'm not familiar with ZK Time & Attendance Devices, but why do you run `getUser` after `disableDevice`? That doesn't sounds right in common sense. Shouldn't you simply read it and disconnect?

Comment: @KoalaYeung
 thanks for ur reply, I also don't understand, this code is like this from the beginning

and the structure i got


1. connect()
2. disabledDevice()
3.requestData()
4.enableDevice()
5.disconnect()

I have also tried your suggestion I removed disabledDevice() it still doesn't work

Comment: Did it ever work?

Comment: getUser followed by disableDevice is the right approach. It restricts the user to edit the user information while your software is reading it.  zklibrary.php is not the standard library provided by zkteco, so either you have to check with the developer of that library or debug it.